# What is the purpose of the code on New York ballots?

Tags: united-states, voting

When I voted in New York (Brooklyn, but presumably ballots are similar statewide), I had my named crossed out in a book so that I couldn't vote twice (I assume). They then removed a sticker from my ballot and placed it next to my name. Then I voted, fed it into the machine, etc.

This sticker with a code seems like it could be used to deanonymize voters. What is its purpose?

Comment: Did you not have to sign the book next to a copy of your signature from your registration form? I always have to (also in Brooklyn).

Comment: I'm not sure if knowing this is relevant to answering your question, but is [this](https://www.verifiedvoting.org/resources/voting-equipment/ess/ds200/) your voting machine?

Comment: @Bobson that looks like the machine I've used since New York stopped using mechanical machines.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to look closely at the codes, you would find that they are not individually unique. The code only represents the specific **version or format of the ballot you voted on**. This is tracked because people who live in *different local election districts* will often be voting *at the same precinct*. The codes simply verify that the person, based on their address, was given the correct version of the ballot.

([Source from Washington state](https://wei.sos.wa.gov/agency/osos/en/pages/ballotsecrecy.aspx), but the same presumably applies in other states.)

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it's the same in New York and Washington?

Comment: @indigochild The more I dig, I think your question is quite valid. Here is a source (https://www2.monroecounty.gov/files/2016%20Inspector%20Manual.pdf) that seems to indicate that barcodes reflect unique voter ID #s. If you really want a definitive answer, I suggest you ask the relevant authority, FOIL if necessary (https://www.elections.ny.gov/FoilRequests.html), and share what you find out.